# "Virtual data frame" approach to data frame manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In the final section of the dplyr vignette *Introduction to dplyr*, dplyr is compared to other approaches to data frame manipulation (such as base R and plyr). In particular, it is mentioned that

> Compared to virtual data frame approaches:
>
> - it [*dplyr*] doesn't pretend that you have a data frame: if you want to run `lm` etc, you'll still need to manually pull down the data
> - it doesn't provide methods for R summary functions (e.g. `mean()`, or `sum()`)

I'd like to understand the context of this comparison.

**Questions**

1. What, exactly, is this "virtual data frame" approach? (The name "virtual data frame" suggests to me that it must be some kind of proxy data frame.)
2. Where can one see this approach in action? What packages use it?

Comment: I believe it's related to dealing with SQL databases: you can create a chain (pipe) of commands as if all of the data were locally stored, but through lazy evaluation, it only downloads data at the last moment. In this sense, it is a "virtual data.frame" in that it is virtually local, yet truly local when finally referenced outside of dplyr SQL-aware functions.